# Should I put the game logic inside the draw loop?

Tags: c, draw

I'm making a simple game using CSFML and am wondering if I can make my code more efficient.

Right now the code looks like this inside the main function's game loop:

```
    // game logic
    for (int i = 0; i <= perf.arramount; i++)
    {
        UpdateBody(&body[i]);
    }


    // clear
    sfRenderWindow_clear(window.window, window.bg);
    

    // draw
    for (int i = 0; i <= perf.arramount; i++)
    {
        sfRenderWindow_drawRectangleShape(window.window, body[i].rect, NULL);
    }

    // display
    sfRenderWindow_display(window.window);
```

I was told to do things in the order: logic, clear, draw, display. However, would there be any issues with me putting the logic inside the draw loop like this?

```
    // clear
    sfRenderWindow_clear(window.window, window.bg);

    // draw
    for (int i = 0; i <= perf.arramount; i++)
    {
        UpdateBody(&body[i]);
        sfRenderWindow_drawRectangleShape(window.window, body[i].rect, NULL);
    }

    // display
    sfRenderWindow_display(window.window);
```

Would it slow down the draw calls or make the code more efficient?

I'm not sure if this specific library may be different from others, so even a general answer is appreciated.

Comment: Is the program suffering from inefficiency? Do you need to update the display before the computation is complete? Keep separate the form and the function. The appearance of the game is an entirely different matter from the game engine.

Comment: no matter what you do, you'll always have the same delay between 2 displays, so the difference won't be seen from the user POV. However, it's always good to keep things separated! The 1st  version looks much more cleaner to me ;)

Comment: [Gaffer On Games](https://gafferongames.com/categories/game-physics/) is always a good place to start (especially "Integration Basics" and "Fix My Timestep!") I concur, your first code layout with the separate functions within the game loop is much easier to read.

Comment: What if an update of Entity 2 changes the position of Entity 1 but entity 1 is already drawn?

Comment: You will see flashing.  You have already cleared the screen and now you are slowly drawing and doing the logic as well.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I was under the illusion that drawing was another process that used time that could otherwise be used for game logic. I'll keep things separate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How to structure your game is your design decision.
You will be the first to notice problems with it.
But here is my experience. I learned that in the game logic loop you have calculations which are definitly needed, they also tend to need information on how much time has passed. In the drawing loop you just need to visualise the result of the calculations. As soon as you are going to split into threads, the timing of the need to calculate and to visualise will change. You are likely to want to calculate more often than you draw, while you want to draw always completly (except for more advanced FPS-based level of detail rendering....).
So there are multiple aspects which might make you want to keep those two things apart.
What I did was having a calculation step (which by my design gets real time information as a parameter of elapsed seconds) and a separate drawing step. That way you *can* have them in one parent loop, but you are free to move them at any point AND you are protecting yourself from confusing those two steps.